# Accessing static variable returns empty string

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, load, static-members

Config.as loads an XML file and stores the content of the XML file in the static variable "xml". I am trying to access this variable within Main.as class but it returns an empty string.

I think the problem is the loading process. I am trying to access the variable before the XML file actually gets loaded. Any ideas?

```
public static var xml:XML; // returns null
public static var xml:XML = new XML(); //returns ""

public class Config {

    public static var xml:XML = new XML();
    //public static var xml:XML;

    public function Config() {
        loadXML("config.xml");
    }

    private function loadXML(url:String):void{
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteXML);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    private function onCompleteXML(e:Event):void{
        xml = new XML(e.target.data);
        trace("loaded");
    }

    private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
        trace("Load operation failed!" + e.text);
    }

    public static function getXML():XML{
        return Config.xml;
    }

public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public function Main () {
        new Config();

        trace(Config.xml);
        trace(Config.getXML());
    }
}
```

Edited:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public function Main ()
    {
        new Config();
    }

    public static function xmlHasLoaded():void
    {
        //now do something
        trace(Config.xml);
        newFunction();
    }

    public function newFunction():void{  //don't work
        trace("new function");        //public static function newFunction():void{} works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: to keep all Config variables private you would need to create getter and setter functions.

e.g.

in your Main Class:

```
public static var _instanceOfConfig:Config;

public class Main extends MovieClip {
public function Main () {
_instanceOfConfig = new Config();
}
}
```

in your Config class:

```
private var xml:XML;
```

//note this is not a static function as it needs to access the xml class variable.

```
public function getXML():XML {
return xml;
}

public function setXML(newXML:XML):void {
xml = newXML;
}
```

Then from your other classes you could use:

```
import Main;

trace(Main._instanceOfConfig.getXML().somenodename);

Main._instanceOfConfig.setXML(_thenewxml);
```

**EDIT.** This has something to do with declaring static functions. Static functions can't access variables or apparently methods outside the scope of itself.

Try this.

In your Main Class, add:

```
public static var _instanceOfMain:Main;
```

and in your Main constructor function

```
_instanceOfMain = this;
```

and make this function not static.

```
public function xmlHasLoaded():void
```

Then in your Config class:

Change Main.xmlHasLoaded(); to Main._instanceOfMain.xmlHasLoaded();

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Look again in the edited post. The actual code throws an error: "Call to a possibly undefined method newFunction". If I use the "static" keyword in the function declaration it works. That means i must declare all the methods that comes after the XML file was loaded as static methods. Could it be another way?

Comment: I must declare all the methods that come after loading the XML file as static. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should wait for the loading of the xml to complete before trying to access it.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
public function Main () {
new Config();
}
}

public function xmlHasLoaded():void {

//now do something
trace(Config.xml.somenodename);

}



public class Config {

public static var xml:XML;
private var loader:URLLoader;

public function Config() {
    loadXML("config.xml");
}

private function loadXML(url:String):void{
    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteXML);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

private function onCompleteXML(e:Event):void{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace("loaded"+xml);
    trace(xml.somenodename);

    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteXML);
    loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    loader = null;

    Main.xmlHasLoaded();

}

private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace("Load operation failed!" + e.text);

    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteXML);
    loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    loader = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just one clarification: you forgot the static keyword in the function definition "public function xmlHasLoaded():void".

Comment: One last question please. Say for example i have this in my code... (look in the main post). It would throw me an error unless i define the function as static. I want to use Config.as class to host global variables from entire application which i get them from the XML file. An easy sollution is to declare explicit public all variables, but i am not so pleased with the idea. Isn't another way?